# Why am I getting these random values?

Tags: c, function, pointers

Ok, so I have to write a function that uses pointers to convert days into years, weeks, and days. Here is the function.

```
int convertTime(int days, int *y, int *w, int *d){
  if (days < 0 || y == NULL || w == NULL || d == NULL){
    printf("An error has occured\n");
    return 1;
  }else{
    *y = days / 365;
    *w = (days % 365) / 7;
    *d = ((days % 365) / 7) % 7)
    return 0;
  }
}
```

and here is the part in the main function where I am calling it.

```
// Tests convertTime
  int days = 1000;
  int y2 = 0, w2 = 0, d2 = 0;
  int *y = NULL, *w = NULL, *d = NULL;
  y = &y2, w = &w2, d = &d2;
  convertTime(days, y, w, d);
  printf("Expected output: 2 years, 38 weeks, 4 days\n");
  printf("Actual output: %d years, %d, weeks, %d days\n");
```

and it prints out

```
Expected output: 2 years, 38 weeks, 4 days
Actual output: -127184896 years, -132560896, weeks, -135499072 days
```

Comment: your compiler should warn you about missing `printf()` arguments e.g., `gcc`, `clang` do that by default.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to pass your variables to printf. Fix the last line like this:

```
printf("Actual output: %d years, %d, weeks, %d days\n", y2, w2, d2);
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the other answer you need to pass in the values to the `printf`.

Also you need to check the return value for `convertTime`